# Async/await in PCL Profile 158 targeting Android and IOS too

Tags: c#, asynchronous, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, portable-class-library

I have a PCL Profile 158 with Android and IOS. I also want to use async/await.
I find some solutions for this problem, but I can't got it working.

When I try to use await, visual/xamarin studio shows an error saying: Type 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task<...>' is not awaitable.

Is there any way to get it working or an alternative to use async/await operations?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Did you also install the nuget package for Microsoft.Bcl.Async? I think you need that to get async/await in a PCL.

Comment: I tried before, but it shows an error of incompatibility: Could not install package 'Microsoft.Bcl.Build 1.0.13'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets 'portable-win+net45+sl50+wp80+MonoAndroid10+MonoTouch10'

Comment: @ThiagoRomam Install the latest version of NuGet (2.7.2 or higher), and you should be able to install the Microsoft.Bcl.Async NuGet package in your portable library.